# Ratio in sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a geometric series where the common ratio is $r$ ($r^2$ is not $1$)  the sum of the first $13$ terms is three times the sum of the first $6$ terms.How do I find in any order the ratio of the sum of the first $18$ terms to the sum of the first $12$ terms. I have already searched the net for ratios involving series but I still cannot figure it out?

Comment: Do you know what the formula is for the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: Is there any reason to imagine that the answer is pleasant?   Easy enough to solve numerically; I got r ~ -.91019 and the answer about 1.2061 (trusting that no computational errors were made).  Haven't found any "natural" ways to write those numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the formula for the sum of geometric series:

```
S(n) = a(1-r^n) ÷ 1-r
```

Now applying this formula, I would make n=13. Simplify that statement as much as possible. So you should get something like this

```
a(1-r^13) ÷ 1-r  =  3*a(1-r^6) ÷ 1-r
```

Now that we have substituted the formula, we will work our way to getting our variable values.

we can immediately cancel '1-r' and 'a' from each side so you end up with

```
1-r^13 = 3(1-r^6)
1-r^13 = 3-3r^6
-2 = r^13-3r^6
-2 = r^6 ( r^7 - 3)
-2 ÷ (r^7 - 3) = r^6
```

and so on, you get the idea. After you find r, it is simple enough to find 'a'. Then use those values to find the 18th and 12th sums, and compare.